# how to auto-number each line in <p> element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to auto-number each line that will be generated while displaying a
`<p>` element.

Perhaps using counters in CSS?
I'm looking for something along the lines of p:first-line, except for every line of the `<p>` element

something like:

```
p:each-line {
    counter-increment line_num;
}

p:each-line:before {
    counter(line_num) " " ACTUAL-LINE;
}
```

Can I do this with simple CSS code? How else could I achieve this?

I have an element called message, and I don't know in advance how many lines
of actual text will be formatted using that element style. If I change the
max-width for example and that forces more/fewer lines, I'd like this to automatically
number correctly the actual lines in the element.

```
/* set up the speech bubbles */
p.message {
    position:relative;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:2px solid rgb(74,77,82);
    border:2px solid rgba(74,77,82,.5);
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    max-width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with CSS alone - you would need extra markup or a script. Your example syntax would not be valid CSS as you cannot have pseudo-elements within other pseudo-elements.

Comment: Another solution would be to use a backround image containing the row numbers, positioned left and having a left padding on the paragraph set to >= image width. Then using line-height to match the images row numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Such a task is a little much for CSS alone to handle. It isn't too hard in javascript.

It sounded like a nice little distraction so I played around a bit in jsfiddle. Perhaps this will help even though it's not pure css and uses some jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/rSFUB/2/

Notice that I wrapped the `<p>` text in a div and added a line number div within that absolutely positioned. The javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".message").each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var numbering = self.find(".lineNumbering").first();
        var messageText = self.find("p").first();
        var lineHeight = numbering.text("...").height();
        var lines = messageText.height() / lineHeight;
        var lineNumberingHtml = "";
        for(var i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {
            lineNumberingHtml = "" + lineNumberingHtml + i + "<br />";
        }

        numbering.html(lineNumberingHtml);
    });
});
```

I tested in IE10, Chrome, and Firefox. The only difference between this code in the various versions is the padding on the `.lineNumber` div in order for it to line up with the text. Note this assumes that the line number div text and the paragraph is the same `line-height`.